# r2corba installation fails on OS X

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, corba

I'm trying to install r2corba(1.4.1) on my OS X 10.9.2 and I get this error which I don't know how to resolve. I'm using ruby version 2.1.1.

`ERROR:  Error installing r2corba:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

`Unsupported platform: x86_64-darwin12.0.`

Does it mean that r2corba is no longer supported on OS X?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you report this on the R2CORBA OSPortal, see https://osportal.remedy.nl/projects/r2corba. When you register there you can report an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s the code in `r2corba-1.4.1/rakelib/ext.rb` that detects the platform:

```rb
if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/
  osx_ver_major, osx_ver_minor = (`uname -r`).strip.split('.')[0,2].collect {|n| n.to_i }
  if osx_ver_major == 10
    @@osx_name = case osx_ver_minor
                   when 3
                     'panther'
                   when 4
                     'tiger'
                   when 5
                     'leopard'
                   when 6,7,8
                     'snowleopard'
                 end
  end
  platform_error unless @@osx_name
end
```

I tried hacking it and returning `snowleopard` regardless. The gem *built*, but I have no way to test it. Given that so much software broke with each iteration between 10.6 and 10.9, I’m sceptical that it’ll work, but if you want to try it, find where the gem is stored (`gem environment` will help with that, look at the `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY`), edit the above file to have this at the end instead:

```
  @@osx_name = 'snowleopard'
end
```

Then run `gem install r2corba` and it will install from the existing files.

By the way, the problem appears to be a dependency on [ACE](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html), which doesn’t include support for anything beyond Snow Leopard and hasn’t been updated since May 2013.

Comment: I downloaded its source code and tried to compile it but it gave me the same error. I noticed the point you mentioned and tried to use snowleopard name but it didn't work out.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you didn’t successfully set `@@osx_name`, because the gem installed for me when I did that. If the gem *did* build, then I think you have your answer: it’s not compatible with versions of MacOS newer than 10.6.

Comment: Please report this on the Remedy IT osportal! The 1.4.1 version of R2CORBA does include the latest ACE version available at that moment. Newer versions are available, but that requires work because that ACE/TAO version has to be validated against R2CORBA.

Comment: Finally I was able to pass the error by setting the `@@osx_name`; however I faced another problem. After about 10 mins of compiling it stopped because of an error.


`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_rb_apply", referenced from:
R2TAO_RBFuncall::FuncArgArray::rb_invoke(unsigned long) const in required.`

`ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
`

Comment: I downloaded ACE+TAO source and I finally got it compiled.
But when I want to build the gem itself using rake, I get this error:

`ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`

It's trying to build `libr2tao.dylib`

Comment: libr2tao.dylib is a library from R2CORBA, it could be that you misconfigured, have you followed the instructions online at https://osportal.remedy.nl/projects/r2corba/wiki/R2CPG_Ch2_IR

Answer (score 2):

We have released yesterday R2CORBA 1.5.1. It isn't formally tested on MacOSX but it does include some fixes that should resolve this, for more details see the [Remedy IT website](http://www.remedy.nl).

Answer (score 0):

R2CORBA 1.4.1 has been released before the latest release of MacOSX was available. The real solution is to report this to Remedy IT (the author of R2CORBA) through their support site at http://osportal.remedy.nl. When Remedy IT has enough interesting/funding to justify the work to make a new R2CORBA release this could be solved.